# Updating Lists in SwiftUI after property changes

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui

I have a program that has two main classes, **Team** and **Player**. Team has an array built in which holds 23 instances of the **Player** class, all with their own properties and methods. In the main content view of my app, I display a list of these **homeTeam.players** and each row has a **.contextMenu** with the option to call **editName()** from the individual Player.

When **editName()** is called it will open an alert and allow the user to enter a new name into the textField which then saves it and changes the name property of the Player.

My issue is that the list then does not update on the main view and the player name stays the same, however when you go to change it again, the name is in place in the textField, so it has changed, just isn't being displayed.

Player Class:

```
    class Player{
        var playerName: String = ""
        var id = UUID()

        init(playerName: String){
             self.playerName = playerName
        }

        func editName{
            //Displays alert with text field
            self.playerName = newName
        }
    }
```

Team Class:

```
    class Team{
        var teamName: String = ""
        var players: [Player] = [Player("Player 1"),
                                 Player("Player 2"),
                                 Player("Player 3"),
                                 Player("Player 4")] //Continues for 23 Players

        init(teamName: String){
             self.teamName = teamName
        }

    }
```

Swift View:

```
    List(homeTeam.players) {player in
        HStack{
            Text("\(player.shirtNumber) - \(player.playerName)")
            Spacer()
            Text("\(player.timerText)")
        }
        .contextMenu{
            Button(action: {player.editName()}) {
                Text("Edit Name")
                Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
            }                    
        }
    }
```

I'm still relatively new to SwiftUI, but have some experience with UIKit and storyboarding, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make your models struct and add view model as ObservableObject holding your model as published property.

Comment: Change the player class to a struct? Team as well? And then what do I change to an ObservableObject? Sorry, not very experienced with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- add conformance of Team to ObservableObject
- be sure homeTeam is marked as @ObservedObject var homeTeam: Team
- when it comes time to edit a player's name, call a (new) method on
  Team, not the Player, perhaps named changeName(player: Player, to
  newName: String) to make the change for you
- be sure that changeName() calls the Team method
  objectWillChange.send() so the view knows that the team has changed
  (this method is part of the ObservedObject protocol). that's what
  causes the view to redraw.

Answer from HackingWithSwift (@delawaremathguy) - https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/updating-lists-in-swiftui-after-property-changes/4910

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible way (not tested, typed inline)

```
struct Player: Identifiable {
    var playerName: String = ""
    var id = UUID()

    init(playerName: String){
         self.playerName = playerName
    }

    mutable func editName{
        //Displays alert with text field
        self.playerName = newName
    }
}

struct Team{
    var teamName: String = ""
    var players: [Player] = [Player("Player 1"),
                             Player("Player 2"),
                             Player("Player 3"),
                             Player("Player 4")] //Continues for 23 Players

    init(teamName: String){
         self.teamName = teamName
    }
}
```

and now view model as

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
   @Published var homeTeam = Team()
}

and updated view

struct ContentView: View {
   @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()

   var body: some View {
    List(Array(vm.homeTeam.players.enumerated()), id: \.1) { (index, player) in
        HStack{
            Text("\(player.shirtNumber) - \(player.playerName)")
            Spacer()
            Text("\(player.timerText)")
        }
        .contextMenu{
            Button(action: {vm.homeTeam.players[i].editName()}) {
                Text("Edit Name")
                Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
            }                    
        }
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: Testing this on an empty view it works just how I want; when I try and implement it into my project I get an error "escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter" on this code: 
`let enter = UIAlertAction(title: "Enter", style: .default) { (_) in
            self.playerName = alert.textFields![0].text!
        }`
Any ideas?

Comment: You should update model only via view model, because model now is value type.

Comment: How would you advise getting the user to input a new name, without a textView and alert as I'm currently using?